# How to use Logging with multiprocessing in Python3

Tags: python-3.x, logging, multiprocessing

I am trying to use python built in logging with multiprocessing.
Goal -- is to have errors logged to a file called "error.log"
Issue -- The errors are printed in the console instead of the log file. see code below

```
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import repeat
import logging


def data_logging():
    error_logger = logging.getLogger("error.log")
    error_logger.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)-12s %(levelname)-8s %(message)s')
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('error.log')
    file_handler.setLevel(logging.ERROR)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)
    error_logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return error_logger


def check_number(error_logger, key):
    if key == 1:
        print ("yes")
    else:
        error_logger.error(f"{key} is not = 1")


def main():
    key_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3]
    error_logger = data_logging()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        executor.map(check_number, repeat(error_logger), key_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

function check_number checks if numbers in list key_list is 1 or not
if key = 1, prints yes to the console, if not i would like the program to add {key} is not = 1 to the log file.
instead with the code above it prints it to the console. please help if u can. this is a mini example to my program so don't change the logic

Answer (score 0):

Be able to pass a logger instance to the child processes, you must have been using python 3.7+. So here is a little about how things work.

### The basic

Only serializable objects can be passed to the child process, or in the other way of speaking, `pickleable`. This includes all primitive types, such as `int`, `float`, `str`. Why? because python knows how to reconstruct (or unpickle) them back to an object in the child process.

For any other complex class instance, it is `unpickable` because the lack of information about the class to reconstruct its instance from serialized bytes.
So if we provide the class information, our instance can be `unpickable`, right?

To a certain degree, yes. By calling a `ClassName(*parameters)` it certainly can reconstruct the instance from scratch. So, what if you have modified your instance before it gets pickled, like adding some attributes that not in the `__init__` method, such as `error_logger.addHandler(file_handler)` ? The `pickle` module is not that smart to know every other thing that you added to your instance afterward.

### The why

Then, how does python 3.7+ can pickle a `Logger` instance? It doesn't do anything much. It just saves the logger's name which is a pure `str`. Next, to unpickle, it just calls `getLogger(name)` to reconstruct the instance. So now you understand your first complicated problem: the logger that the child process reconstructs, is a default logger without any handler attached to it and a default level of `WARNING`.

### The how

Long story short: use [logger-tt](https://github.com/Dragon2fly/logger_tt). It supports multiprocessing out of the box.

```
import concurrent.futures
from itertools import repeat
from logger_tt import setup_logging, logger


setup_logging(use_multiprocessing=True)


def check_number(key):
    if key == 1:
        print ("yes")
    else:
        logger.error(f"{key} is not = 1")


def main():
    key_list = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 1, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 5, 4, 3, 4, 3]
    error_logger = data_logging()
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=1) as executor:
        executor.map(check_number, key_list)


if __name__ == '__main__':
        main()
```

If you want to start from the beginning, there are some more problems that you need to solve:

- interprocess communication: `multiprocessing.Queue` or `socket`
- logging using `QueueHandler` and `QueueListener`
- offload the logging to a different thread or child process

The above things are needed to avoid duplicating log entries or missing a part of the log or no log at all.